# Flutter how set background on fix size

Tags: flutter, background, size

I need help. At the moment I'm trying to implement a background on my login page.
My problem is that I use a custom shape painter which shows my background.

To make my login page more dynamic I have added a function `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,` to move the `textfield` over the keyboard.

But now I have the problem that my background will be smaller if I click on my text field.

Here is my login page:

[image]

[image]

My code:

```
class _DebugPage extends State<DebugPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: customSubAppBar('Debug', context),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          //my custom shape painter
          Expanded(
            child: CustomeShapePainer(),
          ),
          //my custom widgets
          _body(context),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a way to set the background on fix size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try set widget `CustomeShapePainer` wrap Widget Stack. I don't remember exactly but in some projects I did

```
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            color: AppConstants.bgColor,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: CurvePainter(),
              child: Stack
```

Comment: Thx Gome, i got a solution (: Here my soution: class _DebugPage extends State<DebugPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: customSubAppBar('Debug', context),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: LimitedBox(
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: ShapePainter(),
            child: Stack(
              children: [_body(context)],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}